# Why does $(2/p)=\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{p}\right)$?

Tags: number-theory

Browsing one of my favorite video game sites, there was a post asking about the derivation of the formula
$$
\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} 2\cos(2\pi k/p).
$$

I know that $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$, but I'd never seen a formula in terms of cosine, it seems computational more involved. Anyway, out of curiosity is there a derivation or reference to a derivation? Many thanks.

Comment: I take it $p$ must be odd. $p>?$ For $p=3$ for instance this statement is clearly wrong.

Comment: The second equation is wrong for all $p$ as well. Please edit the question.

Comment: @nbubis $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$ denotes the Legendre symbol, so I'm quite sure the second equation is correct. And for $p=3$, we have $(2/3)=-1$ since $2$ is not a residue modulo $3$. The product on the right hand side evaluates to $2\cos(2\pi/3)=2(-1/2)=-1$ so the formula indeed works in that instance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Have to say, it's an awfully ambiguous symbol.

Comment: This must be some awfully cool video game I recon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer I am writing was already given and for some reason deleted by ryu jin. It seemed like a good answer to me, so here it is again as CW.

There is a more general theorem: For $a$ relatively prime to $p$, we have
$$\left( \frac{a}{p} \right) = \prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \frac{\sin (2 \pi ak/p)}{\sin (2 \pi k/p)}.$$

Plugging in $a=2$ and the identity $\sin(2 \theta) = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$ gives your formula.

Proof: For $a$ as above, and $k$ an integer in the interval $[1, (p-1)/2]$, we can reduce $ak$ modulo $p$ to get an integer in $[-(p-1)/2, (p-1)/2]$. Write that integer as $\epsilon(k) \phi(k)$ where $\epsilon(k)$ is either $1$ or $-1$ and $\phi(k) \in [1,(p-1)/2]$. Since $m \mapsto \sin( 2 \pi m/p )$ is periodic modulo $p$ and an odd function, we have
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \sin (2 \pi ak/p) = \prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} {\Big(}\epsilon(k) \sin (2 \pi \phi(k)/p) {\Big)} = \prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \epsilon(k)  \prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}  \sin (2 \pi \phi(k)/p)$$

By [Gauss's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28number_theory%29),  we have $\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} \epsilon(k) = \left( \frac{a}{p} \right)$. Also by Gauss's lemma, the map $\phi$ is a bijection from $\{ 1,2, \ldots, (p-1)/2 \}$ to itself, so the second factor is $\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} \sin (2 \pi k/p)$.

So
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \sin (2 \pi ak/p) = \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) \prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} \sin (2 \pi k/p)$$
as desired.

Comment: @ryu jin: Let me know if you object to me writing this for some reason.

Comment: why I edelted it: How does this answer the question? – hmIII 6 hours ago

Comment: thanks for the proof @DavidSpeyer

Comment: Yes, thanks for the proof!

Answer (score 2):

For odd prime $p,$

$$\cos px+i\sin px=(\cos x+i\sin x)^p=\sum_{0\le r\le p\cos^{p-r}x(i\sin x)^r}$$

Equating the Real parts, $$\cos px=\cos^px-\binom p2 \cos^{n-2}x\sin^2x+\binom p4\cos^4x\sin^4x+\cdots$$
$$=\cos^px(1+\binom p2+\binom p4+\cdots)+\cdots+(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\cos x$$
$$=2^{p-1}\cos^px+\cdots+(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\cos x$$

If we put $x=\frac{2k\pi}p,\cos px=1$ where $k$ is any integer.

So, the roots of $$2^{p-1}\cos^px+\cdots+(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\cos x-1=0$$ are $\cos \frac{2k\pi}p$ where $0\le k\le p-1$

So, $$\prod_{0\le k\le p-1}\cos \frac{2k\pi}p=\frac1{2^{p-1}}\implies \prod_{1\le k\le p-1}\cos \frac{2k\pi}p=\frac1{2^{p-1}}$$ as $\cos\frac{2k\pi}p=1$ for $k=0$

Now, $\cos\frac{2(p-k)\pi}p=\cos(2\pi-\frac{2k\pi}p)=\cos\frac{2k\pi}p\implies \cos\frac{2k\pi}p\cos\frac{2(p-k)\pi}p=\cos^2\frac{2k\pi}p$

$$\implies \prod_{1\le k\le p-1}\cos \frac{2k\pi}p=\prod_{1\le k\le \frac{p-1}2}\cos\frac{2k\pi}p\prod_{\frac{p-1}2< k\le p-1}\cos\frac{2k\pi}p=\prod_{1\le k\le \frac{p-1}2}\cos^2\frac{2k\pi}p$$

So, $$\prod_{1\le k\le \frac{p-1}2}\cos^2\frac{2k\pi}p=\frac1{2^{p-1}}\implies \prod_{1\le k\le \frac{p-1}2}\left(2\cos\frac{2k\pi}p\right)^2=1$$

Now, $\cos\frac{2k\pi}p<0$ if $\frac\pi2<\frac{2k\pi}p<3\frac\pi2\implies \frac p4< k<\frac{3p}4$ which in our case reduces to $\frac p4< k\le \frac{p-1}2$

So $k$ has $\mu=\frac{p-1}2-\lfloor \frac p4\rfloor$ values for which $\cos\frac{2k\pi}p<0$, 
$$(-1)^\mu\prod_{1\le k\le \frac{p-1}2}2\cos\frac{2k\pi}p=1\implies \prod_{1\le k\le \frac{p-1}2}2\cos\frac{2k\pi}p=(-1)^\mu$$

Observe that $\mu,\frac{p^2-1}8$ have same parities.

For example, for $p=8n-1, \frac{p^2-1}8=\frac{(8n-1)^2-1}8=8n^2-2n$ and $\mu=4n-1-(2n-1)=2n$